# What is done to used balls in cricket

Tags: cricket

What is done to worn out balls? Are they recycled, reused or do they end up in the landfill?

Answer (score 2):

Cricket balls when they have been used in matches are generally kept by teams to be used as spare balls should the ball need to be changed as it has been damaged or lost.

If they are not suitable for this or if enough spares are around players and coaches will keep them for practice use.

Once they are no good at all even for practice, I have seen a number of uses from knocking in bats, dogs toys etc.  They would normally be thrown in the ordinary rubbish as I am not aware of anyone that could recycle a ball.

Having said that I've never thrown a ball away and I have played for 5 years and umpired for 20.